# как определить количество введенных цифр в строке?

Tags: c++

По условию строка `char W[n]` (n=256). Далее производится ввод через `cin.get`.

Как пройти по этой строке и посчитать количество введенных цифр?

Comment: Не очень понятно... Есть строка и надо найти, сколько в ней цифр? Пройтись циклом и проверкой `isdigit`... Но при чем тут `cin.get`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

После ввода строки циклом с проверкой каждого символа функцией `isdigit();`
Если `isdigit()` возвращает `true`, то увеличиваем счетчик и так до конца строки.

Comment: А чем это отличается от ответа Harry?